# angular material vertical position issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

what i have currently is this:

[image: screenshot1]
[image]

As its visible, the `md-card` in the center is going below the `md-toolbar`.

Similar problem occurs on scrolling down.

I noticed if I **remove** the `1000x400` image, then the position is fine because there is no overflow in y-axis.

The problem only occurs during overflow.

> Note: the centered `md-card` exists inside a `ui-view`, if that makes any difference.

**Edit**: Added [this codepen](http://codepen.io/ishankhare07/full/WrzKJN/) to demonstrate the problem. Notice the grey background when scrolling down.

Comment: initial fix with positioning issue solved with `layout="row"` for the `ui-view` tag. The bottom color inconsistency still remains though.

Comment: Add a plunkr/codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initial fix with positioning issue solved with layout="row" for the ui-view tag.

The bottom `grey background` inconsistency was solved by simply adding a wrapping `div` inside `body`, wrapping all the content inside, I will soon post a codepen demonstrating the problem and its solution.

**Edit**: [codepen](http://codepen.io/ishankhare07/full/adYaWj/) depicting the solution